# Teamcity and Grails

Tags: grails, teamcity

My current requirement is:

I have to package my grails app and use teamcity for continuous build.
The only problem is **the build agents don't have groovy and grails installed** (don't ask why)

I want to package my app with Groovy and Grails directories and check in Git. So that there is no dependency on installing groovy and grails on the build agents. And the package has everything to run the app.

Can anybody please help.

Please let me know if you want me to rephrase my question.

Comment: Are you absolutely stuck with TeamCity ?  Hudson has some really nice Grails and Git integration that makes it very easy to build, test and deploy Grails apps; if this might work for you, let me know and I'll post a more detailed answer.

Comment: yes I am the corporation using Teamcity and has all praises for it. Have no choice. :(

Comment: well Gareth thanks for you reply atleast I was able to run grails and groovy on my build machines, however now stuck in another problem.
here is more:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560493/grails-plugins-and-team-city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this is what I did:

I checked in both groovy and grails inside GIT.

[image]

`then I added environment variables inside TeamCity relative to the checkout directory`

[image]

and then added the following parameters:
[image]

`You can write war in the command-paramters to generate a war`

This worked for me...
cheers