# Grails Plugins and Team City

Tags: grails, teamcity

This is my current scenario:

I have checked in my grails app code + Groovy Folder + Grails Folder using GIT to teamcity.
Now when I try to run it Teamcity trows me this error:

```
[13:33:35]: Error reading remote plugin list [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect], building locally...
[13:33:35]: Plugins list cache doesn't exist creating..
[13:33:36]: Unable to list plugins, please check you have a valid internet connection: Connection refused: connect
[13:33:37]: Reading remote plugin list ...

[13:33:38]: Plugins list cache doesn't exist creating..
[13:33:39]: Unable to list plugins, please check you have a valid internet connection: Connection refused: connect
[13:33:39]: Plugin 'db-util' was not found in repository. If it is not stored in a configured repository you will need to install it manually. Type 'grails list-plugins' to find out what plugins are available.
[13:33:39]: [delete] Deleting directory C:\Documents and Settings\RiskSystemsBuildSA\.grails\1.2.2\projects\f8c726f1e64e048c\plugins\tomcat-1.2.2
[13:33:41]: Process exited with code 1
[13:33:41]: Build finished
```

I think I will have to package the plugins inside my app and then check them in GIT.

Please let me know your say on this matter.

Much Appreciated.

p.s.`Teamcity correctly picks up the installed groovy and grails as I store .\grails and .\groovy in my teamcity environmen variables.`

Comment: It looks like your build server doesn't have access to the internet.

Comment: Hi uthark,
the thing is ... I do not want the build agent to download the plugins. Somehow I want to include the plugins in my app.
Is there a way to include the plugins as part of the app?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally achieved it. I added a line in the build.config file:

```
grails.project.plugins.dir="./grails/plugins"
```

This basically creates a dir plugins inside your project directories and downlaods all the zips in here. Next I checked in all the zips and the plugin directory in GIT. Since, everything was checked-in, teamcity didn't have any reason to moan about.

Everything else is going smooth now.